# \subparagraph{name} not recognized in IEEEtrans document.

Tags: errors, document-classes

The information I have found on the web indicates that the `\subparagraph` level should be available in an IEEEtrans article. I'm using TeXLive 2009, `pdflatex`.

The relevant preamble line:

`\documentclass[conference, 11pt]{IEEEtran}`

In the document itself, the usage is

```
    \paragraph{paragraph} 

    a bunch of text

    \subparagraph{subparagraph}

    a bunch more text
```

The error I'm getting is: `ERROR: Undefined control sequence.`

Is this a usage mistake--that is, I'm not using the correct command name or I'm not including a package--or is it a function of the IEEEtrans conference class that it does not allow `\subparagraph`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading Section VI of the [IEEEtran](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) manual will show you the allowed heading levels. More than the listed ones are not possible without manual intervention.

Comment: RTFM. Always good advice.